# Bound on norm of difference of two vectors using their angle

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, angle

For two unit vectors $u$ and $v$, prove that if 
$$\sin(\angle u,v)\leq l$$
We have:
$$\exists \theta\in \lbrace -1,1\rbrace :\quad \|u-\theta v\|_2\leq\sqrt{2} l$$
I see this in the application of Davis-kahan theorem to the community detection in chapter 4.5.3 of the book "High dimensional probability" by Roman Vershynin.

My try:

$$ \sin(\angle u,v)\leq l \Rightarrow \sqrt{1-\langle u,v\rangle^2}\leq l$$
$$\|u-\theta v\|^2_2= 2-2\theta\langle u,v\rangle$$

What should I do next?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I tried to write sin in terms of the inner product of two vectors but can't relate it to the norm of the difference. Also expanding the norm of difference didn't help.

Comment: Adding to your question exactly what you tried will help us help you.

Comment: "I can't relate it to the norm of the difference" - then try to relate it to the **square** of the norm of the distance.